Kotlin Android: 'TelephonyCallback' detect phone number
To be honest, I've searched a lot on the subject, but since is a lot of changes on latest API it is still not clear for me if it is possible somehow to get the phone number of the caller.
The main idea is have service, which uses TelephonyCallBack class
object : TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
        when (state) {
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
                Log.d("incCall", "Incoming call detected") // <-- here I need to get the number
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                Log.d("incCall", "Call answered")
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                Log.d("incCall", "Call ended")
            }
        }
    }
}

Any suggestions or resources would be great,
Thanks

I know that, but stil I am not sure if is it possible to get the number

Add READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_CALL_LOG permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml like this
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

Create a Receiver class which extends BroadcastReceiver to listen to incoming call events
class IncomingCallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) {
            val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
            if (state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) {
                val incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
                Log.d("IncomingCallReceiver", "Incoming number: $incomingNumber")
            }
        }
    }
}

Register the reciever in the onCreate method of Activity
registerReceiver(IncomingCallReceiver(), IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"), RECEIVER_EXPORTED)


I think that's better approach for my case, since i need to be executable even if the app is killed, also i have to display some composable depends of EXTRA_STATE_RINGING, all those are achievable with this way right?

I'll mark this as correct one, it partially cover my case, so maybe will help someone else.

Yes, it's possible. To detect a phone number you need to use the TelephonyManager object. Look at two full versions of the code (Kotlin & Java) to get an idea of how to programmatically obtain a subscriber's phone number. Below is a short version of the code:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />


var phoneNumber: TextView? = null

fun obtainNumber(): Unit {
    val manager = this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val obtainedPhoneNumber = manager.line1Number
    phoneNumber?.text = obtainedPhoneNumber
}


Permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

here is TelephonyCallback class
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.telephony.TelephonyCallback
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat

class MyTelephonyCallback(private val context: Context) :
    TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {

    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
        when (state) {
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
                    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    val telephonyManager =
                        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
                    val incomingNumber = telephonyManager.line1Number
                    Log.d("IncomingCall", "Incoming number: $incomingNumber")
                } else {
                    Log.d("Permission", "READ_PHONE_STATE permission not granted")
                }
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                Log.d("CallState", "Call answered")
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                Log.d("CallState", "Call ended")
            }
        }
    }
}


I have tried to use one and it works. Providing the steps to follow the required outcome.
If you are targeting versions above Android 13, then you have to ask READ_PHONE_NUMBERS runtime permission from the user. Here is the code for that.
Add these lines to your AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Handling Permissions in an Activity/Fragment
private val requestPermissionsLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
) { permissions ->
    // Handle the permissions response
    val grantedPermissions = permissions.filterValues { it }
    val deniedPermissions = permissions.filterValues { !it }

    if (grantedPermissions.isNotEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted: ${grantedPermissions.keys}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Proceed with accessing the phone number or other telephony features
    }

    if (deniedPermissions.isNotEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions denied: ${deniedPermissions.keys}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Inform the user why the permission is required
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // Trigger the permission request
    checkAndRequestPermissions()
}

private fun checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    val permissions = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    )

    // You can add logic here to check if permissions are already granted
    requestPermissionsLauncher.launch(permissions)
}

Create a class for TelephonyCallback
class MyTelephonyCallback(private val context: Context) : TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {

override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
    when (state) {
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
            // No active call
        }
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
            // Phone is ringing
            val telephonyManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
            val phoneNumber = telephonyManager.line1Number // This may return null or empty depending on SIM card configuration
            if (phoneNumber != null && phoneNumber.isNotEmpty()) {
                println("Detected phone number: $phoneNumber")
            }
        }
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
            // Call is active
        }
     }
  }
}

Register the callback in an Activity/Fragment
val telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
val myTelephonyCallback = MyTelephonyCallback(this)
telephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback(mainExecutor, myTelephonyCallback)

Please note, Sometimes even with all permissions granted, some devices or carriers may block access to the phone number (e.g., getLine1Number() returning null).
